# How to get file path + file name into a list?

Tags: python, directory-listing

I am trying to get a list of strings with the file path and the file name. 
At the moment I only get the file names into the list.

Code:

```
hamFileNames = os.listdir("train_data\ham")
```

Output:

```
['0002.1999-12-13.farmer.ham.txt', 
 '0003.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt', 
 '0005.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt']
```

I would want an output similar to this:

```
['train_data\ham\0002.1999-12-13.farmer.ham.txt',
 'train_data\ham\0003.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt',
 'train_data\ham\0005.1999-12-14.farmer.ham.txt']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have access to the directory path you could just do:

```
dir = "train_data\ham"
output = map(lambda p: os.path.join(dir, p), os.listdir(dir))
```

or simpler

```
output = [os.path.join(dir, p) for p in os.listdir(dir)]
```

Where `os.path.join` will join your directory path with the filenames inside it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058554/8586227.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Python 3.5 or higher, skip `os.listdir` [in favor of `os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), which is both more efficient and does the work for you (`path` is an attribute of the result objects):

```
hamFileNames = [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(r"train_data\ham")]
```

This also lets you cheaply filter (`scandir` includes some file info for free, without `stat`-ing the file), e.g. to keep only files (no directories or special file-system objects):

```
hamFileNames = [entry.path for entry in os.scandir(r"train_data\ham") if entry.is_file()]
```

If you're on 3.4 or below, you may want to look at the PyPI `scandir` module (which provides the same API on earlier Python).

Also note: I used a raw string for the path; while `\h` happens to work without it, you should *always* use raw strings for Windows path literals, or you'll get a nasty shock when you try to use `"train_data\foo"` (where `\f` is the ASCII form feed character), while `r"train_data\foo"` works just fine (because the `r` prefix prevents backslash interpolation of anything but the quote character).